# Undeclared identifier onlyowner

Tags: solidity

Getting error with this code

```
**/*

Meta Mining Token

 https://github.com/Overtorment/MetaMining

  */

  import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin- 
  solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Pausable.sol";
  import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin- 
  solidity/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol";

  pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

 contract MetaToken is Pausable{

string public name = 'MetaMetaMeta! Token';
uint8 public decimals = 8;
string public symbol = 'M3T';
string public version = '0.4.0';

uint256 public blockReward = 1 * (10**uint256(decimals));
uint32 public halvingInterval = 210000;
uint256 public blockNumber = 0; // how many blocks mined
uint256 public totalSupply = 0;
uint256 public target   = 0x0000ffff00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000; // i.e. difficulty. miner needs to find nonce, so that (hash(nonce+random) < target)
uint256 public powLimit = 0x0000ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff;
uint40 public lastMinedOn; // will be used to check how long did it take to mine
uint256 public randomness;

address public newContractAddress;

function MetaToken() Ownable() {
    lastMinedOn = uint40(block.timestamp);
    updateRandomness();
}

/// update randomness, will be used to find next Nonce
function updateRandomness() internal {
    randomness = uint256(sha3(sha3(uint256(block.blockhash(block.number-1)) + uint256(block.coinbase) + uint256(block.timestamp))));
}

/// returns `randomness` used in PoW calculations
function getRamdomness() view returns (uint256 currentRandomness) {
    return randomness;
}

/// pure, accepts randomness & nonce and returns hash as int (which should be compared to target)
function hash(uint256 nonce, uint256 currentRandomness) pure returns (uint256){
    return uint256(sha3(nonce+currentRandomness));
}

/// pure, accepts randomness, nonce & target and returns boolian whether work is good
function checkProofOfWork(uint256 nonce, uint256 currentRandomness, uint256 currentTarget) pure returns (bool workAccepted){
    return uint256(hash(nonce, currentRandomness)) < currentTarget;
}

// accepts Nonce and tells whether it is good to mine
function checkMine(uint256 nonce) view returns (bool success) {
    return checkProofOfWork(nonce, getRamdomness(), target);
}

/*
    accepts nonce aka "mining field", checks if it passess proof of work,
    rewards if it does
*/
function mine(uint256 nonce) whenNotPaused returns (bool success) {
    require(checkMine(nonce));

    Mine(msg.sender, blockReward, uint40(block.timestamp) - uint40(lastMinedOn)); // issuing event to those who listens for it

    balances[msg.sender] += blockReward; // giving reward
    blockNumber += 1;
    totalSupply += blockReward; // increasing total supply
    updateRandomness();

    // difficulty retarget:
    var mul = (block.timestamp - lastMinedOn);
    if (mul > (60*2.5*2)) {
        mul = 60*2.5*2;
    }
    if (mul < (60*2.5/2)) {
        mul = 60*2.5/2;
    }
    target *= mul;
    target /= (60*2.5);

    if (target > powLimit) { // difficulty not lower than that
        target = powLimit;
    }

    lastMinedOn = uint40(block.timestamp); // tracking time to check how much PoW took in the future
    if (blockNumber % halvingInterval == 0) { // time to halve reward?
        blockReward /= 2;
        RewardHalved();
    }

    return true;
}

function setNewContractAddress(address newAddress) onlyOwner {
    newContractAddress = newAddress;
}

event Mine(address indexed _miner, uint256 _reward, uint40 _seconds);
event RewardHalved();
}**
```

Error :

```
browser/XGD..sol:100:56: DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier.
function setNewContractAddress(address newAddress) onlyOwner {
                                                   ^-------^
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems your environment didn't import correctly the OpenZeppelin contracts. Try to change the references to the OpenZeppelin contracts to get the raw source code. Here are the addresses you should change in your two imports:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Pausable.sol
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/master/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol

Answer (score 1):

Change line `contract MetaToken is Pausable` to `contract MetaToken is Pausable, Ownable`. As `onlyOwner` is defined in Ownable contract. You have to inherit that contract too, only then you will able to access `onlyOwner`.

Answer (score 0):

Just import the contract which implement the modifier with the same name, or write one by your own:

1) declare

```
address owner;
```

2) in the constructor of the contract add

```
owner = msg.sender;
```

3) declare the modifier:

```
modifier onlyOwner() {
require (owner == msg.sender);
_;
}
```

or something like it, and that’s all.

This is a straightforward and very largely known code... may be it could be useful for you to research and read something more around before to try to compile and deploy a token contract like that, which implies many simple but detailed concepts.